# HP Z400 with Xeon W3520 2.66 Ghz

Tags: intel-core-i7, xeon

I have a HP Z400 with Xeon W3520 2.66 Ghz. Would it be a benefit if I replace the mentioned CPU with I7 930 for they both use LGA1366?  Would it even work?

http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13276_na/13276_na.PDF

Comment: It is unlikely to work; that motherboard is designed to be compatible only with a limited number of Xeon processors.  Physical compatibility of the socket is not enough.

Comment: I was in doubt myself. Thanks very much Debra.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to work; that motherboard is designed to be compatible only with a limited number of Xeon processors.  Physical compatiblity of the socket is not enough.

Comment: With apologies, this was not meant to be posted as both a comment and an answer!

Answer (score 0):

HP Z400 actually does work (although unofficially) with an i7-930 but you must change original ECC memory for non-ECC since i7 doesn't support it. I actually tested this out of curiosity and it worked, this was tested with latest Z400 BIOS loaded prior to swap. In your case I'm not sure what the benefit would be to swap Xeon with same frequency i7, if you can get a higher end version for cheap like W3565/i7-960 or better then it could give you a slight bump in performance.